# Please tell me why this deadlocks: Reading and writing from Paramiko exec_command() file-like objects -- ChannelFile.close() does not work

Tags: python, paramiko

```
import paramiko, threading

def Reader(src):
    while True:
        data = src.readline()
        if not data: break
        print data


client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect("172.17.0.2", username="test", password="test")

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("dd of=readme.txt")

reader = threading.Thread(target=Reader, args=(stderr, ))
reader.start()

stdin.write("some data")
stdin.flush()
stdin.close()

reader.join()
```

This code waits forever at the join(). If I remove the stderr writing thread it works as expected, with the correct text being written to the file 'readme.txt', but I then lose the dd stderr messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probblem is in `stdin.close()`. According to Paramiko's doc (v1.16):

> **Warning:** To correctly emulate the file object created from a socket’s `makefile()` method, a `Channel` and its `ChannelFile` should be able to be closed or garbage-collected independently. **Currently, closing the `ChannelFile` does nothing but *flush* the buffer.**

So you have to use <del>`stdin.channel.close()`</del>.

---

**UPDATE:**

Since *stdin*, *stdout* and *stderr* all share one single channel, `stdin.channel.close()` will also close *stderr* so your `Reader` thread may get nothing. The solution is to use `stdin.channel.shutdown_write()` which disallows writing to the channel but still allows reading from the channel.

Verified it works fine:

```
[STEP 101] # cat foo.py
import paramiko, threading, paramiko

def Reader(src):
    while True:
        data = src.read()
        if not data: break
        print data,

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect("10.11.12.13", username="root", password="password")

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("dd of=/tmp/file")

reader = threading.Thread(target=Reader, args=(stderr,) )
reader.start()

stdin.write("some data")
stdin.flush()
stdin.channel.shutdown_write()

reader.join()
[STEP 102] # python foo.py
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
[STEP 103] #
```